# In DrRacket how do I make a list of lists

Tags: list, lambda, racket

Essentially all I am trying to do is make a list of lists in DrRacket 'Intermediate Student with Lamda' but I am unsure how to approach this.

I'm still a novice with using Racket so I at least understand that I have to use lambda to be able to create a list of list, at least this is one method I am aware of but I still don't know what to do.

I want to make a function that when you type

`(list (list  1 2 3) (list 3 4 5) (list 6 7 8))` it will compute something.

I need to know this so I can solve a question I am currently working on which is this question:

> Write a function (keep-counts L threshold mincount), where L is a
>   (listof (listof Num)), and the other parameters are both Num.
>
> This function returns a list containing all the values in L which
>   contain at least mincount values greater than threshold.

Example:

```
(keep-counts (list (list 1 1 2 5) (list 1 4 4 1) (list 6 6 4 7)) 2 2) => 
(list (list 1 4 4 1) (list 6 6 4 7))
```

This is yielded since only these two lists contain at least two values greater than 2.

Comment: `(list (list 1 2 3) (list 3 4 5) (list 6 7 8))` is already a list of lists. I'm not sure what your question is asking. "compute something" is very vague. Please edit your question to be more specific about what you're having trouble with, and see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you're unsure about how to do that

Comment: Alright, I'll edit the question, i'm trying to know how to make a function that will allow  me to make a list of lists, it's necessary to answer a question i'm working on. I'll just post the question then so my question can be better understood. Ok i've edited the question.

Comment: "*I have to use lambda to be able to create a list of list*" - Why? Lambda creates a function, not a list.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure to do to be honest then. I was thinking I might have to map lambda to a helper function but also have to create another function using lambda to allow me to create a list of lists. I may be totally wrong but this is what I assumed was possible. I tried this but just failed and was not able to make a list of lists but I have heard that you can make a list of lists using lambda, regardless any solution I will be satisfied with.

Comment: What do you mean you "just failed"? `(list (list 1 2 3) (list 3 4 5) (list 6 7 8))` is valid code and it creates a list of lists. What more do you want?

Comment: How is just writing a list of lists manually going to help me solve the question I am trying to solve, i need to create a function. I'm supposed to  make a function that when i input a (listof (listof Num)) and two different Num values it will only return specific lists. The question I wrote explains what I am trying to achieve. I wasn't asking for assistance for the question originally but I may need assistance I suppose now.

Comment: "*How is just writing a list of lists manually going to help me solve the question I am trying to solve*" - It isn't. But all you asked was "*how do I make a list of lists*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can be expressed in terms of higher-order procedures:

```
(define (keep-counts lst mincount threshold)
  (filter (λ (sl)
            (>= (count (λ (e) (> e mincount))
                       sl)
                threshold))
          lst))
```

The above code states: filter all the sublists where the number of elements greater than `mincount` is above a given `threshold`. The solution literally writes itself!

```
(keep-counts (list (list 1 1 2 5) (list 1 4 4 1) (list 6 6 4 7)) 2 2)
=> '((1 4 4 1) (6 6 4 7))
```

Comment: Is there a way I can alter the code where instead of count, length is used. I'm currently trying to do this. I didn't know what count did before in Racket so I used docs.Racket-lang.org and came up with

 (>= length (filter lambda (t) (>t mincount)) (map s))) instead of 

(>= (count (lambda (t) (> t mincount))

 I unfortunately can not use count and filter-map so based on the definition of those functions I came up with that piece of code. 

It doesn't work though which I was expecting so i'm curious how do I write the count function using the length, filter, and map function.

Comment: count is just (length (filter...)) using the same predicate on the same list

Comment: Actually nevermind, I solved my error. Map was unnecessary in that piece of code. I just needed to add filter and length. (edit) I wrote this as you answered my question, thanks though.